# libgdx modelinstances position changed after calling camera.position.set or camera.lookat

Tags: mobile, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I have my camera with below initial settings:
camera.lookAt(200f, 100f, -300f);
camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 0f);
and the modelinstances displayed as below:
[initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoCsD.jpg)

I coded a button on click and call the set of methods:
camera.lookAt(200f, 100f, -300f);
camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 0f);

and the screen became as below:
[call camera methods again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utyBT.jpg)

Between the initial image and the button click, I have done nothing else.
To troubleshoot this problem, I've tried adding camera.up.set(xyz), camera.normalizedUp() but did not solve the problem.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's not the ModelInstances moved. It's the camera moved by the resize(). Under the resize() method, I've coded viewport.update(width, height, true) which will center the camera within the viewport and thus the camera moved without my notice. Also, the skybox is coded in a way that it will moved with the camera and makes it looks like the camera has not moved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set position first, then do the lookat() call

Comment: have tried this sequence but no effect ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same camera position vector object to the modelinstances position vector object, so when the camera moves the modelinstances do so. Just create a new vector for each modelinstance, set its position to the camera pos `myModelPos.set(camera.pos)`,and everything should be fine.

I made an [example of basic mario 64 movement on this guthub](https://github.com/hllink/libgdx-mario-movement), hope it helps.

Comment: I found out the root cause. Thanks for your mario 64 example anyway.

Comment: can you share the solution and accept it as the right answer? More people could have the same question.

Comment: Please find my solution below and I accepted already. Cheers!